# grails properties

Tags: grails, configuration, properties

I am having some big troubles using external properties with grails. 
In config.groovy I have:

```
grails.config.locations = ["file:grails-app/conf/config.properties"]
```

this is my config.properties file:

```
test.prop.test=this is a test
```

and this is in my code:

```
println grailsApplication.config["test.prop.test"]
```

Has anyone any idea why this does not work?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the config options using single string keys that include dots, as opposed to the multi-level `grailsApplication.config.test.prop.test` then you need to use `flatConfig` instead:

```
grailsApplication.flatConfig["test.prop.test"]
```

Answer (score 0):

in external config

```
this.is.myname="My name is Hello!"
```

in your controller

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder

String name= ConfigurationHolder.config.this.is.myname;
```

this is work for me...with using grails 2.1.1